# R: Is it possible to download the latest version of Google Chrome directly in R?

Tags: r, rselenium

I am working with the R programming language.

I am using the Selenium library.

Earlier (in August 2023), my code used to run without any problem - but now (November 2023) I am getting the following error:

```
 library(RSelenium)
 library(wdman)
 library(netstat)
 
> selenium()
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
....
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
$process
PROCESS 'file27547a8c5781.bat', running, pid 14124.
    
    binman::list_versions("chromedriver")
$win32
[1] "113.0.5672.63" "114.0.5735.16" "114.0.5735.90"

 seleium_object <- selenium(retcommand = T, check = F)
 
 remote_driver <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever = "114.0.5735.90", verbose = F, port = free_port())

Selenium message:session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 119.0.6045.105 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-4N315DJ4', ip: '192.168.2.249', os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_341'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00ECA813+48355]


Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
     Summary: SessionNotCreatedException
     Detail: A new session could not be created.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
Check server log for further details.

#################################
# rest of R/selenium script (currently does not work
#remDr =  remote_driver
#remDr$navigate("https://www.google.com/maps")


# Search for the CN Tower
#search_box <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#searchboxinput")
#search_box$sendKeysToElement(list("CN Tower", key = "enter"))

#Sys.sleep(5)

# Get the URL of the current page
#url <- remDr$getCurrentUrl()[[1]]

# Extract the longitude and latitude from the URL
#long_lat <- gsub(".*@(-?[0-9.]+),(-?[0-9.]+),.*", "\\1,\\2", url)
#long_lat <- unlist(strsplit(long_lat, ","))
###############################################
```

It seems like that there is a problem with the version of Chrome I was using. However, it looks like I have the correct version of Chrome?

[image]

To make my code more fluid, I want to modify my code so that it downloads the most recent version of Chrome/drivers and resolves this problem automatically.

**Is it possible to do this directly in R?**

Thanks!

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] netstat_0.1.2   wdman_0.2.6     RSelenium_1.7.9 duckdb_0.7.1-1  DBI_1.1.3      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.8.3       rstudioapi_0.13    xml2_1.3.3         knitr_1.39         rappdirs_0.3.3     R6_2.5.1          
 [7] rlang_1.0.6        fastmap_1.1.0      httr_1.4.4         caTools_1.18.2     tools_4.1.3        xfun_0.30         
[13] binman_0.1.3       tinytex_0.45       KernSmooth_2.23-20 cli_3.4.1          e1071_1.7-9        semver_0.2.0      
[19] htmltools_0.5.3    class_7.3-20       yaml_2.3.5         digest_0.6.29      assertthat_0.2.1   processx_3.8.0    
[25] ps_1.7.2           bitops_1.0-7       curl_4.3.2         evaluate_0.19      rmarkdown_2.14     proxy_0.4-26      
[31] compiler_4.1.3     classInt_0.4-3     jsonlite_1.8.4
```

Comment: I believe the issue you are seeing is the result of already having the latest version of Chrome -- `wdman` currently knows only about older ChromeDriver releases (up to 114, the one you have), which will not work with Chrome 115+. There's an open pull request to address this - https://github.com/ropensci/wdman/pull/39 . It's difficult to recommend it or provide it as an answer, but if you are OK with testing unreleased & not-yet-accepted code and understand all the risks, you can install it through `remotes` from gtihub. Or wait until it gets accepted and new CRAN release is made.

Comment: @margsul: thank you so much for your reply! If I understand correctly, I can fix this problem by downloading a newer version of the "wdman" library? And this can be done using the remotes::() function? If you have time, can you please write an answer just to make sure I am understanding correctly? Thank you so much for all your help   - much appreciated

Comment: You might already know this, but you can execute system commands from R with `system()`.  Could be something like `system("wget http://...chrome.deb; sudo apt install chrome.deb")`

Comment: @ Arthur: thank you so much for your reply! Can you get this R selenium script to run?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know what you are trying to do in r with selenium. Are you **testing** a website or **scraping**?

If you are scraping I’d recommend finding a way to use **chromium** instead of the chrome selenium driver. Usual implementation is downloading the chromium browser and then interacting with it similar to selenium with chrome. Big advantage is you don’t have version mismatches with chrome not being updated or the selenium chrome driver version not matching. You choose the version of chromium to use and it only changes when you specify a new version.

Comment: @ lastlink: thank you so much for your answer! I have never heard of/used chromium before. Can you please walk me through the necessary steps? e.g. do I download it using command prompt? and from there, how do I modify my existing R Selenium script so that it works? Thank you so much!

Comment: You could prob use something like https://github.com/rstudio/chromote there are multiple ways to download chromium, I’ve used it in c# with no issues. No install needed just downloaded the exe.